Tensorflow optimization help - ANN unable to optimise seemingly simple time series prediction problem
A basic Tensorflow NN model is unable to optimise a simple synthetic time series prediction problem. I have tried various configurations and optimizers, but the model cannot beat a naive "flat" baseline prediction, and cannot get close to the optimal solution (prediction = t0 + (t0 - t-1)).
The time series has been constructed to have a regular linear increase, which reverses direction and changes the rate of increase every 100 steps. See image.
The model is fed 2 time steps and predicts 1 time step ahead.
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    # Shape: (time, feature) => (time*feature)
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=10, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1),
    # Shape: (output) => (time, feature)
    tf.keras.layers.Reshape((1, -1)),
])
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(),
              optimizer=optimizer,
              metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.MeanAbsoluteError()])

Despite trying various optimizers and some of their parameters (e.g. learning rate), and higher epoch counts I cannot get close to the optimal solution.
One optimal solution that takes the most recent time step and adds the difference between that and the previous time step. This can be implemented using a 4 node hidden layer, weights of 1 or -1, no biases, and a relu activation.
Manually configuring the weights and biases and evaluating the model gets the result I would like, so I am confident that my setup and data windowing is working.
Any advice on how to configure my model or optimizers to get a better result, or an understanding of why it cannot find the optimal solution would be appreciated!
Edit: I've seen some improvement with smaller batch sizes (4, 8 etc.) rather than the default 32. I had also inadvertently switched shuffling off at one point, which didn't help with metrics. I can now get close to and occasionally beat the "flat" baseline (not consistently) - but it is still way off from the optimal solution that I have put in the data.
Could it be that the optimal solution is in a hard to find area of the solution space? I'm not a trained data scientist, so not sure how to visualise that. But the built in gradient descent optimizers aren't seeming to find it.
I'm using Tensorflow 2.16, and python 3.11 on a Windows 11 system.
More on the code...
Model compile:
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    # Shape: (time, feature) => (time*feature)
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=10, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1),
    # Add back the time dimension.
    # Shape: (output) => (time, feature)
    tf.keras.layers.Reshape((1, -1)),
])
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(),
              optimizer=optimizer,
              metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.MeanAbsoluteError()])

Model fit:
model.fit(self.window_gen.train,
          epochs=20,
          validation_data=self.window_gen.val,
          callbacks=None,
          verbose=1)

Window generator:
ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.timeseries_dataset_from_array(
        data=data,
        targets=None,
        sequence_length=3,
        sequence_stride=1,
        shuffle=True,
        batch_size=32) # Has improved with smaller batch size.

ds = ds.map(self.split_window)

Using data windows based on the Tensorflow time series tutorial at: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series
Configured as input with 2 time steps, and label with 1 timestep and an offset of 1. Default batch size of 32. Shuffled.
Synthetic dataset - as described above. 100 time step periods of monotonically increasing or decreasing values (but rate of increase varying between each direction reversal). To create a degree of uniformity for the model to latch onto, but some variability across the dataset. 10,000 time steps generated.
Trained with (70%) - validation (10%), and 20% reserved for test.
rng = np.random.default_rng(42)
signal = [0]
sign = 1
delta = 0.5
for i in range(1,10000):
    if not (i-10) % 100:
        sign *= -1
        delta = rng.random() * sign
    signal.append(signal[-1] + delta)
signal = np.array(signal)
signal = (signal - np.mean(signal)) / np.std(signal)

Signal

Metrics

Sample plot


Can you share the code you used to generate the data? This would allow us to debug your code easier and try alternatives.

Not easily in its entirety as I have custom classes etc. I'll add some more of the core tensorflow / NN model code above.

I could try and create a standalone set of code for "debugging", but that would take some effort and I believe this is more of a configuration issue, or maybe me developing a better understanding of the limitations of an ANN. Should a basic ANN be able to fit a relatively simple dataset as I constructed to a high degree of accuracy?

Sorry - misread your comment as "all the code". Added the data generation code above. If you can build NN to get an MAE close to the optimum (approx. 1.5 x10-4) then please tell me how!

If I initialise my model's weights and biases to the optimum solution (requires a minimum of a 4 unit hidden layer) and set a very low learning rate then it stays close to the optimum. Increasing the learning rate means it moves away, but not by too much. ** My conclusion is that despite a seemingly simple built in solution to the data the optimum is hard to find, and requires a low learning rate to get close to it (making it even harder to find).** Any suggestions on configurations that would deal with this better... model architecture, optimizers, adaptive learning rate?
